# Monitoring Windows Server performance to a file

Tags: windows, monitoring

I would like to monitor a windows server's performance by polling the CPU/RAM/Network IO usage over a period of time every 1 minute and write these values to separate files depending on the monitored channel.

Is there any open source/free tool out there besides XPerf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PerfMon.exe tool that ships will all versions of windows and windows server.

- Run PERFMON.EXE.
- Right-click Data Collector Sets/User Defined.
- Click New/Data Collector Set.
- Name it. -Create from template or manually after you get the hang of
  it.
- Select a template like "system Performance".
- Confirm or modify the path to the file to be created. -
- Set the user id to use for the Run As.
- Click "Finish".
- right-click the newly created set and Start.
- Stop when you want and find the report in the selected location,
  typically: %systemdrive%\PerfLogs\Admin\User