# How do I export Task Manager stats into a file with PowerShell?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, task-manager

I want to see if it's possible to pipe CPU/Memory usage and processes into something like a csv every few minutes with PowerShell.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

By using "Task List" I was able to send information into a CSV file:

```
tasklist /FO csv > *path*
```

I can do this on a schedule with a scheduled task, but it's not exactly clean as the data gets written into individual csv files.

EDIT2:

I've opened a ticket with Microsoft through my OEM support contact. Performance monitor is the ideal solution but as I've said below it's not working as expected. They are investigating.

Comment: You can use Windows Performance Monitor to capture CPU, memory usage and a lot more.

Comment: @Atzmon perfmon is not working as expected for me since available mbytes counter is incorrect. I asked another question on this about it, but it wasn't answered. Essentially it's reporting 50% available when in actuality none is available according to the Event Logs and Task Manager.

Comment: Does the Get-Process "cmdlet" give you the right numbers?  http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_process.htm

Comment: @stamps What have you tried?

Comment: @root see edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with this.

```
Get-WMIObject WIN32_PROCESS | `
Sort-Object -Property ws -Descending | `
Select processname,@{Name="Mem Usage(MB)";Expression={[math]::round($_.ws / 1mb)}},@{Name="ProcessID";Expression={[String]$_.ProcessID}},@{Name="UserID";Expression={$_.getowner().user}} | `
Export-CSV test.csv -Append
```

Output:

```
ProcessName    Mem Usage(MB)       ProcessID    UserID
OUTLOOK.EXE    180                 7132         username
chrome.exe     160                 208          username
WINWORD.EXE    158                 14100        username
```

[Source](http://ricotroubleshooting.blogspot.com/2013/01/get-top-memory-usage-using-powershell.html)

Comment: Thanks this works, I just now need to put it on a schedule a figure out a way to continually add data points to single file.

Comment: It is already using `-Append`

Answer (score 0):

I love Powershell, and you could do this with Powershell, but why?!
Perfmon and Data Collector Sets are a much better fit for this task.
See [Monitoring Windows Server performance to a file](https://superuser.com/questions/578585/monitoring-windows-server-performance-to-a-file/578698)

Comment: See my comments above. I've talked directly to Microsoft OEM support. They've determined there's a bug in PerfMon which in my case is what I'm seeing - 50% RAM availability whereas in actuality it is around 4% availability. Task manager represents it correctly but PerfMon does not.